# Fileinput python reuse

Tags: python, file, memory, file-io

I've been programming a script in python that draws some kind of fractals.
The problem is that in that algorithm I need to use a veeeeeery large numpy matrix.
Because of that (and it's impossible to avoid the usage of the matrix) I've decided to save the matrix on the hard disk and read from the file line to line, go to the element that matters, change it in the file and iterate again.
I'm using fileinput with python this way and it actually works, but sooooo slow because it has to open and close the file a lot of times:

```
fii = fileinput.input("file.txt", inplace=1)
for i, line in enumerate(fii):
    if i == yi:
        offset = (1 + equis*(6))
        line = line[:offset-2] + str(int(line[offset-2])+1) + line[offset-1:]
        if firstfunc:
            line = line[:offset] + str(int(line[offset])+1) + line[offset+1:]
    print line,
fii.close()
```

So I thought, there must be a way to "reuse" the fileinput so it has not to open the file a lot of times, and just only one time.
A way to only replace one character in the file without any problem opening it 1 time.

This way it does not work (it only works 1 time).

```
fn=fileinput.input("file.txt", inplace=1)
for n in range(points):
    (x,y) = itera(x,y,dimy,prob,scale,diff,fn)
fn.close()
# This means opening it 1 time and passing the pointer to the function instead of opening
# it one time per iteration.
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!!

Comment: Just to say that access to drive vs RAM access are not the same, and so your process will be definitely slower.

Comment: You can use SQLite instead of raw file.

Comment: How big is "veeeeeery large"?

Comment: Large enough to not fit in the RAM, I mean, it's like a 10.000x10.000 (int,int) tuple matrix, or even bigger.

Comment: SQLite to store the matrix in a database?
The access will be fast enough?